# 'int' object has no attribute 'deg'

Tags: python-3.x, csv

In my program I'm using a file csv with values like that:

0.3987,-38.0349
1.7577,-66.5549
3.0406,-62.0202
3.3333,-26.5936
...
...

```
from astroquery.skyview import SkyView
from astropy.coordinates import ICRS, Galactic, FK4, FK5, SkyCoord
from astropy.table import Table
from matplotlib import pyplot

import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import csv
import io, os
import astropy.units as u
import pyfits
import numpy as np
import matplotlib

catalogue = pd.read_csv('cat7.csv', delimiter=(','))
catalogue.columns = ['ra', 'dec']
df1 = catalogue[['ra','dec']]
ra = []
dec = []

for r in df1['ra']:
    ra.append(r)
for d in df1['dec']:
    dec.append(d)

os.mkdir('images')
path = os.getcwd()
tree = path+'/images/'

for i in range(1, len(df1)):    
    img = SkyView.get_images(position=SkyCoord(ra[i], dec[i], frame='icrs', unit=(u.deg, u.deg), obstime='J2000'), survey=['DSS2 Blue', '2MASS-J', '2MASS-K', 'WISE 3.4', 'WISE 22', 'GALEX Far UV'],pixels='150,150',coordinates='J2000',grid=False, gridlabels=False)

    for h in img:

        x = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 14))
        ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (0, 0))
        ax1.imshow(img[0][0].data, cmap='gray')
        ax1.set_xlabel('DSS2 Blue')
        ax1.set_xticks([])
        ax1.set_yticks([])

        ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (0, 1))
        ax2.imshow(img[1][0].data, cmap='gray')
        ax2.set_xlabel('2MASS-J')
        ax2.set_xticks([])
        ax2.set_yticks([])

        ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (0, 2))
        ax3.imshow(img[2][0].data, cmap='gray')
        ax3.set_xlabel('2MASS-K')
        ax3.set_xticks([])
        ax3.set_yticks([])

        ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (1, 0))
        ax4.imshow(img[3][0].data, cmap='gray')
        ax4.set_xlabel('WISE 3.4')
        ax4.set_xticks([])
        ax4.set_yticks([])

        ax5 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (1, 1))
        ax5.imshow(img[4][0].data, cmap='gray')
        ax5.set_xlabel('WISE 22')
        ax5.set_xticks([])
        ax5.set_yticks([])

        ax6 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (1, 2))
        ax6.imshow(img[5][0].data, cmap='gray')
        ax6.set_xlabel('GALEX Far UV')
        ax6.set_xticks([])
        ax6.set_yticks([])

        try:

            for filename in os.listdir('galaxies'):
                if filename.endswith('.fits'):
                    try:
                        fit = pyfits.open('galaxies/' + filename)
                        flux = fit[0].data
                        flux = np.array(flux, dtype=np.float64)
                        header = fit[0].header
                        start_wave = header['CRVAL1']
                        step = header['CDELT1']
                        w0, dw, n = start_wave, step, len(flux)
                        w = start_wave + step * n
                        wave = np.linspace(w0, w, n, endpoint=False)
                        data = Table([wave, flux], names=(str(header['CRVAL1']), str(step)))
                        until = 5660 - start_wave + 901
                        until = until/step

                        u = int(until)
                        j = (flux[0:u])
                        media1 = sum(flux[0:u])/len(j)
                        media1 = media1+100
                        inc = u + 5
                        k = (flux[u:inc])
                        media_h = sum(flux[u:inc])/len(k)

                        hdu_name = fit
                        name  = hdu_name[0].header['TARGET']
                        ra_fit = hdu_name[0].header['OBSRA']
                        dec_fit = hdu_name[0].header['OBSDEC']
                        m = max(k)+100

                        if(int(ra_fit) == int(ra[i]) and int(dec_fit) == int(dec[i])):                                                             
                            ax7 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (2, 0), colspan=3)
                            ax7.plot(wave, flux, label = name, color='black')
                            ax7.annotate('hα',xy=(6562,m),xytext=(6545,m))
                            plt.ylabel('Counts')
                            plt.xlabel('Wavelength (Å)')
                            x.savefig(tree+name, format='png')
                            plt.close(x)


                    except:
                        continue
        except:
            continue
```

I need compare this numbers with a number of a file .fits. its works, but it work only once time! the second time of loop "for" it show a error: 'int' object has no attribute 'deg'. if a put "try" before "img = Sky..." it jump this function! How compare to other numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a bit carried away with 21st letter of the alphabet:

```
import astropy.units as u
...
... , unit=(u.deg, u.deg), ...
...
    u = int(until)
```

Change it to `import astropy.units as units` and you'll be much happier. Or at least, you won't trash that symbol by assigning an integer value to it.

Comment: Oh! Thank you J_H! your answer brought the solution of the problem! I never imagined that I needed to change "u" to "units"!

Answer (score 0):

As J_H said, is necessary change the value "u" to "units" in import astropy.units as units and ...unit=(units.deg, u.deg), .... After that the code works perfectly. Thanks!!!